# Open Cover of (0,1) by infinite collection of sets

Tags: calculus, general-topology, manifolds

[text given in"Calculus on manifolds"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI88b.png)
In the above text, it's mentioned that no finite collection of open cover of the form $(\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n})$, n $\in N $ can cover the interval (0,1). But if we take n = 1, it gives the inteval (1,0) which does cover the interval (0,1).
So, is the statement given in the book wrong?

Comment: The link you provide clearly specifies $n>1$.

Comment: $(1,0) = \{x\in\mathbb{R}: 1<x<0\} = \emptyset$

Answer (score 4):

You are wrong, because for $n=1$ you get
$$
\left(\frac11,1-\frac11\right)=(1,0)=\emptyset.
$$
You have to consider that
$$
(a,b):=\{x\in\mathbb R~:~a<x<b\}.
$$
Therefore $a>b$ will give $(a,b)=\emptyset$.